# Azure - Accessing Key Vault using User Managed Identity in Java Spring Boot : Error Details: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have a Java Spring boot application that just reads the secret from Azure Key Vault, below are steps used

- Created an Application Registration

[image]

- Copied the App Registration details

[image]

- Generated Secret

[image]

- Granted access on Azure Key Vault

[image]

and below is my Java Spring Boot application

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.contoso</groupId>
    <artifactId>keyvault</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>keyvault</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.3.5</azure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
azure.keyvault.client-id=7a111923-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-31be31d233dd
azure.keyvault.client-key=gt_~k02yF_xxxxxx_vn3r1.GW
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=9cef136a-xxxx-xxxx-b7d3-d9d8a5a84182
azure.keyvault.uri=https://contosokvxxx.vault.azure.net/
```

**KeyvaultApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class KeyvaultApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(KeyvaultApplication.class, args);
   }

  @GetMapping("get")
  public String get() {
    return connectionString;
  }

  @Value("${connectionString}")
  private String connectionString;

  public void run(String... varl) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(String.format("\nConnection String stored in Azure Key Vault:\n%s\n",connectionString));
  }  

}
```

It works and I could read the Secret from Azure Key Vault

[image]

so decided to remove the secrets from the application.properties and commented as below

```
#azure.keyvault.client-id=7a111923-1xxxxxxxx-31be31d233dd
#azure.keyvault.client-key=gt_~k02yF_xxxxxxxx-Hr6vn3r1.GW
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
#azure.keyvault.tenant-id=9cef136axxxxxxx-3-d9d8a5a84182
azure.keyvault.uri=https://contosokvxxx.vault.azure.net/
```

and added an Environment variable as shown below using setx

```
setx AzureServicesAuthConnectionString "RunAs=App;AppId=bb01c08b-xxxxxxxx-106;TenantId=9cef1-xxxxxxx-d9d8a5a84182;AppKey=xxxxxxxx-4Dpg-E3zrj~"
```

The project compiles without any isssues

```
>mvn clean compile package
```

but failed running

```
>mvn spring-boot:run
```

**Error:**

```
11:40:27.334 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source
        at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.addKeyVaultPropertySource(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.java:110)
        at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:47)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Max retries 3 times exceeded. Error Details: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, Network is unreachable: no further information.
        at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.lambda$attemptAsync$1(RetryPolicy.java:116)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error Details: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, Network is unreachable: no further information.

The error means you could not connect to the Azure Instance Metadata Service endpoint, it is a REST Endpoint that is available at a well-known non-routable IP address (`169.254.169.254`), MSI use it to get the token,  it can be accessed only from within the Azure service e.g. web app, VM, etc. Simply put, you could not use MSI(managed identity) in local.

To use MSI get secret from the azure keyvault, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#deploy-to-azure-app-service) to deploy your application to azure web app, enable the system-assigned identity or user-assigned identity, then remove the `azure.keyvault.client-key` from `application.properties`, change the `azure.keyvault.client-id` with the MSI's client id, add it to the access policy of the keyvault, details follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#redeploy-to-azure-app-service-and-use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources).

```
azure.keyvault.client-id=56rqs994-0o66-43o3-9roo-8e3534d0cb23
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=72s988os-86s1-41ns-91ab-2q7pq011qo47
azure.keyvault.uri=https://contosokv.vault.azure.net/
```

Reference - [Tutorial: Reading a secret from Azure Key Vault in a Spring Boot application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault)

Comment: Does it mean that we can't use the MSI on our local machine? Eg: setting the Environment variable, setx AzureServicesAuthConnectionString "RunAs=App;AppId=bb01c08b-xxxxxxxx-106;TenantId=9cef1-xxxxxxx-d9d8a5a84182;AppKey=xxxxxxxx-4Dpg-E3zrj~"

Comment: I don't want to store the Azure Key vault confidential connection details in my Code repo, I may ignore the "application. properties" from checking in into the repo. However how do I ensure that the application works post deployment without the configuration settings?

Comment: I kind want to have the same deployment experience on both the developers machine and on the target servers.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar Yes, it means you cannot use MSI in local, as I mentioned, the IMDS endpoint is just available in azure service. And as I know, the [`AzureServicesAuthConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) is the feature in .net, it also uses the custom service principal instead of MSI.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar From your question, your app should work in local, to ensure it works after deployment, just change the `application.properties` like the doc, and I don't think you can miss the `azure.keyvault.uri` in it.

Comment: May be a stupid question still I don't know the answer. How do I check-in the application.properties file only with azure.keyvault.uri while the development machine still needs other configuration including secrets?

Comment: Does it mean that I have to use two different application.properties files on the development machine and don't checkin the file that has the confidential data?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar Yes, in the dev machine, `application.properties` needs the `azure.keyvault.client-key`, because you are using your own service principal to auth, in web app, you don't need it, because it will use MSI to auth.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to follow this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-spring-boot).

It shows you how to use the Azure App Configuration service together with Azure Key Vault in a Java Spring application. It also sets the environment variables to connect key vault.

These Key Vault credentials are only used within your application. Your application authenticates directly with Key Vault using these credentials without involving the App Configuration service. The Key Vault provides authentication for both your application and your App Configuration service without sharing or exposing keys.

Comment: still this is not addressing the original issue as I have to still have the App configuration endpoint stored in the properties file. Example # Use default application name and no profile configured
# Keys starting with /application/ will be matched
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      appconfiguration:
        stores:
          - connection-string: "Endpoint=https://xxx.azconfig.io;xxxx'

Comment: more over for the purposes of my project, I just want to use the Key vault with Spring boot without storing the credentials on the properties file.

Comment: The environment variables only support to store `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`, and `AZURE_TENANT_ID`. The other properties such as url need to be set in the properties file.