# Spring boot Azure app config & keyvault - unable to continue auth chain

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

For starters, when I don't have any keyvault reference links with my app config, I can pull my value on boot with no issues. However, I am trying to connect my Spring Boot app to my Azure app config resource that has secrets linked to Azure Keyvault. I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-spring-boot#prerequisites

I am getting the error:

```
ERROR 5088 --- [           main] c.a.i.implementation.IdentityClient      : ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, connect timed out.

ERROR 5088 --- [           main] c.a.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential   : Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://{SERVICE-NAME}.azconfig.io/.default]: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, connect timed out.

ERROR 5088 --- [           main] c.a.core.credential.SimpleTokenCache     : Failed to acquire a new access token.
[...]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Max retries 2 times exceeded. Error Details: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, connect timed out.
```

As my understanding, from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887983/azure-accessing-key-vault-using-user-managed-identity-in-java-spring-boot-er), the DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder() is supposed to go through a chain of possible stored auth values to pull and try to access Keyvault. And since the ManagedIdentityCredential should fail because this is only on my local machine (as opposed to being hosted on an Azure VM), it doesn't look like it. It looks like it's getting hung up on trying to connect and reaching the max number of times to retry.

Is there a way for me to force DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder() to skip over the managedIdentityCred one and go directly to the AzureCliCred?

Here's my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's my AzureCredentials.class and what I have tried:

```
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.identity.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.AppConfigurationCredentialProvider;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.KeyVaultCredentialProvider;

public class AzureCredentials implements AppConfigurationCredentialProvider, KeyVaultCredentialProvider {

    @Override
    public TokenCredential getKeyVaultCredential(String uri) {
        return getCredential();
    }

    @Override
    public TokenCredential getAppConfigCredential(String uri) {
        return getCredential();
    }

    private TokenCredential getCredential() {
        return new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build(); // fails, is attempting ManagedIdentityCredential anyways! times out after 3 attempts
//        return new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build(); //fails, is attempting ManagedIdentityCredential but times out after 3 attempts
    }

}
```

spring.factories, bootstrap.yml and the Config bean to reference AzureCredentials is also created (as per the tutorial).

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have your Environment variables setup, which  the default azure credential should try to use. You can find help/samples here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity#credential-classes.

It may be that whatever you are using to run the project hasn't picked up the new Environment Variables and it needs to be restarted.

Comment: This is a good link. Thank you for this. However, adding env variables didn't help. It's still trying to connect via ManagedIdentityCredential method and getting timed out on this.

Furthermore, I'm trying to use my AzureCli credentials instead of env vars.

Comment: Sorry, assumed that because that is what the demo uses. I don't think the  DefaultAzureCredential tries the CLI credential. The AzureCliCredential works for me, have you tried doing an `az login` in your command prompt then retrying?

Comment: No problem. So  DefaultAzureCredential does have the AzureCliCreds, see here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/src/main/java/com/azure/identity/DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.java#L134

However, I should also note that I'm testing the connection to Azure keyvault on a different machine than my host. I mention that because I was able to replicate my exact project on my host and I can access keyvault with no issues.

Comment: Matter a fact, when I use the DefaultAzureCredential (), it tries to use ManagedIdentityCredential but instantly fails because it knows it's not on Azure. I even can specify the AzureCliCredentials and it only goes to that, as expected.


However, on the target machine that I'm trying to run, it's always trying to use ManagedIdentityCredential(), no matter what I try to specify.

Comment: Hm... Given that it sounds like you skipped step 6 in the tutorial and the Credential isn't being created as `@Bean`. I say that as System Assigned Managed Identity is the default if no credentials are given.

Comment: Hmm, I do have that config class with the class defined in the spring factories file - but I can try to play around with that.

Comment: Wow, that was it! Thank you so much! Turns out, I mistyped the directory of my spring.factories. I typed in, "META_INF" and not "META-INF". I found this out by following you suggestion that the AppConfiguration bean was not getting picked up.